# Openerp send email: email template body is not filled in by my object attributes

Tags: email, templates, odoo

I am trying to send an automatic e-mail from my workflow action. Everything went well unless the e-mail body is not filled with my objet attributes. Nevertherless the e-mail is send with the title filled with the right attribute. Here is my code:

```
def _send_mail(self, cr, uid, ids,subject,message, context=None):


        email_template_obj = self.pool.get('email.template')
        template_ids = email_template_obj.search(cr, uid, [('model_id.model', '=', 'mymodule.module')])
        template = email_template_obj.browse(cr, uid, template_ids[0], context=context)
        complaint = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
        email_template_obj.send_mail(cr, uid,template_ids[0], ids[0],True, context=context) 
        return True
```

my email template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <!--Email template -->
        <record id="iso9001_complaint_reject_email" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">Send auto email</field>
            <field name="email_from">name.lastname@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="subject">Your request has been ${object.state}</field>
            <field name="email_to">name.lastname@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_mymodule_module"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True" />
            <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[             
                THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL. DO NOT REPLY.
                Hello,
                We are here to inform you that the request [[object.subject]] you submitted on        [[object.date]] with the following data:
                      | Request - Details
                      |=========================
                      | Number: test
                      |=========================
                      | Responsible Person: [[object.originator_id.name]]
                      | request description: [[object.description]]
                Has not been [[object.state]] and is closed.
                If you have any question, do not hesitate to contact your supervisor.
                Thank you!           
            ]]></field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Why did I receive the e-mail with the title filled in with the right attribute but not the e-mail body?

Answer (score 0):

It is ok, the fact to copy paste from forums create sometimes some problems. I thought that template and report behave the same. In my template below I juste changed [[object.attribute]] with ${object.attribute} like ine title. So now my template is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>

        <!--Email template -->
        <record id="iso9001_complaint_reject_email" model="email.template">
            <field name="name">Send auto email</field>
            <field name="email_from">name.lastname@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="subject">Your request has been ${object.state}</field>
            <field name="email_to">name.lastname@gmail.com</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_mymodule_module"/>
            <field name="auto_delete" eval="True" />
            <field name="lang">${object.lang}</field>
            <field name="body_html"><![CDATA[             
                THIS IS AN AUTOMATED EMAIL. DO NOT REPLY.
                Hello,
                We are here to inform you that the request ${object.subject} you submitted on        ${object.date} with the following data:
                      | Request - Details
                      |=========================
                      | Number: test
                      |=========================
                      | Responsible Person: ${object.originator_id.name}
                      | request description: ${object.description}
                Has not been ${object.state} and is closed.
                If you have any question, do not hesitate to contact your supervisor.
                Thank you!           
            ]]></field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Hope this could help others.